# how to show image that is in another host via ftp?

Tags: php, ftp

I upload my image to another host via ftp. and keep image name in DB. now I have image name but idon't know how to show it.
my host that image stored is download.1hezar.com

I test http://www.download.1hezar.com/public_html/images/image_name and it's not worked, I think I should first login to ftp and then show image, I know how to login and connect to ftp server but i don't now how can I show image in my website.
any body can help?

Answer (score 1):

public_html actually refers to the domain it self
so i presume it is at  download.1hezar.com/images instead

if you want it in your sub domain 
go check the folder that corresponds with the sub domain
and make a folder called images in that corresponding folder and then put the files there

cheers

Comment: it's not just subdomain, it's in another server